# Unable to start logstash using /etc/init.d/logstash start

Tags: ansible, logstash

I'm trying to start the logstash service using below playbook. Output says starting but when I checked the status its in stopped state.

```
---
 - hosts: test
   gather_facts: False
   remote_user: test
   become: yes
   become_user: root
   become_method: sudo
   tasks:
     - name: starting /etc/init.d/logstash start
       shell: /etc/init.d/logstash start
       
     - name: status /etc/init.d/logstash status
       shell: /etc/init.d/logstash status
       register: logstash_status 

     - name: output
       debug:
         msg: "{{logstash_status}}"
```

Output

```
PLAY [test] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

 

TASK [starting /etc/init.d/logstash start] *****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.10]

 

TASK [status /etc/init.d/logstash status] ******************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.10]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/etc/init.d/logstash status", "delta": "0:00:00.021383", "end": "2021-06-02 20:31:17.701169", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-06-02 20:31:17.679786", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Stopped", "stdout_lines": ["Stopped"]}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/test/logstat-config/new.retry

 

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.1.10               : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: You need to check logstash logs to see if there is any errors.Try to start it directly on the server without using ansible to see if there is any error in the logs.

Comment: I'm able to start it manually.
[test@test-server ~]$ /etc/init.d/logstash status
Stopped
[test@test-server ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/logstash start
Starting logstash
[test@test-server ~]$ /etc/init.d/logstash status
Running
[test@test-server ~]$

Comment: So, what is in the log when you start with ansible? Also logstash can take some time to start, don't know if this can influence your playbook. But you need to check logstash/server logs after you run your playbook.

Comment: Managing services through shell in anslble is a bad practice. Before you get into any debugging, you should try to use the agnostic [service module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) or alternatively the specific [sysvinit module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sysvinit_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-sysvinit-module). Other than being a mush better and idempotent way of managing your service, it might actually fix your issue.

Comment: log file is empty when it starts with ansible. But same getting updated when i start it manually. I did wait of 2 mins still its not getting started.

Comment: I tried with sysvinit module as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start the service by running it in background.

```
---
 - hosts: test
   gather_facts: False
   remote_user: test
   become: yes
   become_user: root
   become_method: sudo
   tasks:
     - name: starting /etc/init.d/logstash start
       shell: nohup  /etc/init.d/logstash start &
       register: logstash

 

     - debug:
         msg: "{{logstash}}"

 

     - name: status /etc/init.d/logstash status
       shell: /etc/init.d/logstash status
       register: logstash_status

 

     - name: output
       debug:
         msg: "{{logstash_status}}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [test] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

 

TASK [starting /etc/init.d/logstash start] *****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.10]

 

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.10] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "nohup /etc/init.d/logstash start &",
        "delta": "0:00:00.014488",
        "end": "2021-06-03 17:31:02.914306",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-06-03 17:31:02.899818",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "Starting logstash",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Starting logstash"
        ]
    }
}

 

TASK [status /etc/init.d/logstash status] ******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.10]

 

TASK [output] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.10] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "/etc/init.d/logstash status",
        "delta": "0:00:00.011286",
        "end": "2021-06-03 17:31:03.272873",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-06-03 17:31:03.261587",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "Running",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Running"
        ]
    }
}

 

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.1.10               : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```